# Kotlin companion objects and reflection

Tags: java, reflection, kotlin

Ran into something interesting when using companion objects and Java reflection. I'm not sure if its intended or not, or if I'm just not understanding things fully.

I have this code

```
public class TestClass {
  companion object {
        public platformStatic var data: String? = null
  }
}
```

The `data` field eventually gets filled via reflection from another class.

What I've found is that if I access the class with `TestClass.javaClass`, I get the internal companion class which only has methods for accessing that field. Accessing it via `javaClass<TestClass>()` gets me the expected Java class with full access to the fields.

Am I just missing something obvious? Is there a reason for this behavior?

Comment: Note, in current Kotlin `platformStatic` has changed to an annotation `@JvmStatic`.  Also function `javaClass<T>()` is not `T::class.java` (since `T::class` returns the Kotlin `KClass<T>` and the `.java` extension returns the Java `Class<T>`) ... Also for late initialization of properties see [lateinit](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties) keyword.

Answer (score 3):

Static fields are stored in the outer class to facilitate Java interop: you can say `TestClass.data` in Java to refer to that field (this should be why you marked it `platformStatic` in the first place).

Comment: Note, in current Kotlin `platformStatic` has changed to an annotation `@JvmStatic`